# Can anyone confirm expectations for the game of blackjack?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, gambling

I computed the probabilities and expectations for blackjack in Mathematica and here is what I came up with:

If player is given only the option to stand the expected win per unit bet is

$$
-\frac{631462897715505}{3937376385699289}.
$$

If player is now allowed to hit the expectation is

$$
-\frac{2220691644539301303808782629}{91733330193268616658399616009}
$$

If further player is allowed to double we get

$$
-\frac{1071160328643044865131012313}{91733330193268616658399616009}
$$

and if splitting is also an option we get

$$
-\frac{3305320393577010676623056559}{1192533292512492016559195008117}
$$

There is a reason I posted those values with infinite precision. I modeled the game and used basic probability on the states of this system to calculate them. No simulations, no Monte Carlo, just pure math and careful numbering. Has anyone done something similar to confirm or disprove me ? An internet search didn't reveal much by the way...

Comment: What rules are the dealer following in each case?

Comment: In all cases the dealer plays the same, like a computer: taking card if the score of his hand is less than 17 and stopping if greater or equal to 17. These are standard rules.

Comment: You appear to be repeating (at least, in part) work done by  [Baldwin et al.](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1956.10501334), published in 1956.  Their results weren't given to infinite precision, however, and their value of $-0.006$ for the player's optimal expected win per unit bet isn't close to any of the values you've give (although it's of the same order of magnitude).

Comment: @lonza leggiera Thanks, I was not aware of their work. Is there a way to get the article for free? I have to make sure they use the same rules as me, eg does the dealer hit on soft 17? Is resplit aces allowed? Of course mathematica was not available at that time and I have double checked the calcs in Visual Basic as well.

Comment: @plus1. It's available from [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2281431?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).   If you have access to a good library that subscribes to JSTOR, you can download a pdf of the article.  Otherwise, if you register an account as an [independent reseacher](https://support.jstor.org/hc/en-us/articles/115004760028-MyJSTOR-How-to-Register-Get-Free-Access-to-Content), you can get online access to 6 JSTOR articles a month, but won't be able to download them.

Comment: @lonza leggiera: I can't get this to work because I am not affiliated with any school right now. If you have it could I buy it from you?

Comment: @plus1.  I don't have a copy myself.  I gained access to an online copy through my membership of a local public  library, but did not download it.  While I would have been permitted to do so for my own personal use, selling such a copy to a third party would violate both the library's and JSTOR's terms of use, and almost certainly constitute a statutory offence under Australia's copyright laws, so it's not something I'm prepared to do. However, if you're willing to pay for a copy, you can buy one directly (and legally) from the publisher for $\mathrm{US}\$43$.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

In order to verify these calculations, we need to know what assumptions you're making. For example, a lot of blackjack analysis assumes an infinite deck; in other words the cards are being drawn from the deck "with replacement".

If you're assuming an finite deck, then we'd need to know how many decks are in your shoe.

Although the Dealer's play is completely rigid, you need to specify exactly what decision tables your Player is following. Unless you're computing the optimum strategy on the fly?

You might be using the standard tables, but even those are merely approximations. For example, you should, in general, hit 16 against a 10. But what if you're holding 2 2 2 3 3 4? I'm not so sure you want to hit that hand with so many small cards missing from the deck.

Comment: I am in the case of infinite deck. That is the probability of each card is not affected by which cards are drawn. It's an approximation but it simplifies things alot. I can't solve a finite deck (not yet anyway). I am computing the optimum strategy before hand, for each situation. In other words I have calculated the decision table. If I am playing against a 10 I will hit on anything below 17 and also on soft 17. Doesn't matter how many or which cards I have. I think I have answered your questions and I am available if you have any more.

Comment: What you are refering to is called gambler's falacy, which is the following: If many small cards pass then the next card has higher chance of being a big card. Then there is the inverse fallacy which states that if many small cards are drawn the next card has a higher chance of being small as well. Of course both of these ideas are wrong and the only way to calculate the next card probability is by the frequency of the cards in the shoe.

Comment: When [I.J.Kennedy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/130/i-j-kennedy) wrote his last paragraph, I expect it was under the condition mentioned at the start of the second: "If you're assuming an finite deck, ..."

Comment: In that case you need to know the cards that remain in the shoe. What if before this sequence of small cards came a sequence of 10 tens or faces, I would hit that.